# I think this is a sql problem, but I can't seem to get rid of this error message

Tags: php, mysql

Hey, yeah, I've tried so many times to get rid of this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

I'm thinking it's a sql problem, but it's only a simple query I'm running.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        $connDB = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)
        or die("Connect Error: ".mysql_error());

        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `iimageid` = '" . $iimageid . "'";
        $runSQL = mysql_query($sql, $connDB);

        echo $sql;
    ?>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
            <?  while($display_info = mysql_fetch_array($runSQL)) { ?>
                    <a href="sfd/pimages/<? echo $display_info['vimage']; ?>" rel="lightbox[g]"><img src="sfd/pimages/thumb/"<? echo $display_info['vimage']; ?>">
                    <br>
            <?  } ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Comment: Just a note that might help you later: <a href="sfd/pimages/<? echo $display_info['vimage']; ?>" rel="lightbox[g]">
    <img src="sfd/pimages/thumb/"<? echo $display_info['vimage']; ?>"> have one " too many. You probably mean "sfd/pimages/thumb/<? echo $display_info['vimage']; ?>"

Comment: To expand on Mez's comment - short tags are considered bad because they are deprecated (I think) and are a configuration setting, which means your code can break with configurations that disable short tags.  Correct syntax: <?php echo 'Hello world!'; ?>

Answer (score 1):

Ok nm, I found it pretty quickly after submitting this thing.  $iimageid wasn't being pulled, taken care of now. :)

Comment: Does your code above execute correctly? As it doesn't look like it is in the correct SQL syntax i.e. apostrophes around column/table name)

Comment: Those are backticks, not apostrophes. They're used to indicate that a string represents a column. You typically only NEED them if you use a reserved name for a column or table name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Without the ticks)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE iimageid = '" . $iimageid . "'";
```

or (typecasting to integer)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE iimageid = ". (int)$iimageid;
```

If its an integer value always typecast to integer, then any text string it will automatically set to 0 "For security purposes"

Comment: Alternatively, you can opt not to even execute the statement if the $iimageid is not numeric, using is_numeric.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SQL statement is invalid to me, try:

```
"SELECT * FROM images WHERE iimageid = '" . $iimageid . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a PHP error to me, not MySQL. Those error codes are normally by the PHP interpreter finding something it doesn't like in your code.
You also appear to have not closed off the <a> tag?
And there appears to be an extra " after your 'thumb/' part of the <img> tag.

I would re-write this section;

```
        <?  while($display_info = mysql_fetch_array($runSQL)) { ?>
                    <a href="sfd/pimages/<? echo $display_info['vimage']; ?>" rel="lightbox[g]"><img src="sfd/pimages/thumb/"<? echo $display_info['vimage']; ?>">
                <br>
        <?  } ?>
```

As follows, see if that helps.

```
        <?  
        while ( $display_info = mysql_fetch_array($runSQL) ) { 
             print "<a href=\"sfd/pimages/{$display_info['vimage']}\" rel=\"lightbox[g]\">";
             print "<img src=\"sfd/pimages/thumb/{$display_info['vimage']}\">";
             print "</a><br>\n";
        } 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime someone uses mysql_* functions, baby raptor jesus eats a lolcat. You should start using PDO ( http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php ), and for the part mixing html and php you may prefer the alternative syntax http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php